# Converting decimal to hexadecimal byte in Java Card

Tags: hex, javacard, pkcs#7, pkcs#5

I would like to convert a decimal (integer or short types) in Java to hexadecimal byte in a Java Card environment (only supports byte and short types and possibly int types).

Example:

```
int num = 254
```

Print out result:

```
0xFD
```

My current method of using switches and if-else to handle all 256 scenarios are totally inelegant and would like something much more elegant than simply switches or if-else.

The reason is I want to manually handle PKCS 5/7 paddings on the Java Card in the event the PKCS5 Ciphers are not available somehow as a fallback method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It slipped my mind that you could do:

```
if (num < 256) {
   return (byte) num;
}
```

That should have settled it for now considering the num which is the amount to pad is less than 256 for PKCS 5 and 7 padding as per RFC-1423, RFC-2898 and RFC-5652.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as an hexadecimal byte. In Java a byte consists of 8 bits. When viewed as a number these bits contain a 8 bit two-complement number from -128 to 127. Hexadecimals is a textual representation of values - such as the Java byte - for human consumption.

Integers are usually not supported on Java Card classic, so I'll just show how to convert short values to bytes.

If you are already sure that the short `s` contains a byte in the lower 8 bits then conversion is simple:

```
byte b = (byte) s;
```

if you are not sure you must decide if you want to allow. If you just care about the 8 lower bits: see above.

If you however want to have a positive number 0..255 stored in the byte, you can check using:

```
if (s < 0 || s > BYTE_MAX_UNSIGNED) {
    // do something nasty
}
byte b = (byte) s;
```

or for the negative values -128 to 127:

```
if (s < BYTE_MIN || s > BYTE_MAX) {
    // do something nasty
}
byte b = (byte) s;
```

Of course the values of the constants is:

```
private static final short BYTE_MAX = 0x7F;
private static final short BYTE_MIN = -0x80;
private static final short BYTE_MAX_UNSIGNED = 0xFF;
```

If you keep them `private static final` then these constants will be inlined into your bytecode by the converter.

As you can see the final byte encoding is identical for both cases. This is why two-complement is the default encoding in about every computer on the planet.

Note that regardless of the value of the short, the byte will hold a value from -128 to 127. If you want to convert the byte to a positive value for calculations, you can use:

```
short s = b & BYTE_MAX_UNSIGNED;
```

to get back a positive value from 0 to 255.

Answer (score 0):

There is a class named [`BCDTool`](http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/apis/jc222/javacardx/framework/math/BCDUtil.html#convertToBCD(byte%5B%5D,%20short,%20short,%20byte%5B%5D,%20short)) inside `javacardx.framework.math` package.

> #### Method Summary
>
> `static short convertToBCD(byte[] hexArray, short bOff,short bLen, byte[] bcdArray, short outOff)`
>
> Converts the input hexadecimal data into BCD format.
>
> `static short convertToHex(byte[] bcdArray, short bOff, short bLen, byte[] hexArray, short outOff)`
>
> Converts the input BCD data into hexadecimal format.
>
> `static short getMaxBytesSupported()`
>
> This method returns the largest value that can be used with the BCD utility functions.
>
> `static boolean   isBCDFormat(byte[] bcdArray,short bOff, short bLen)`
>
> Checks if the input data is in BCD format.

Note that this package is optional and your card maybe or maybe not support it.

Comment: BTW I think you don't need to it. Normally when you assign a value to a byte variable, it stores as HEX form not BCD form.